# UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath, Offsetting an Array

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have these two lines of Code loading the text into the UITableViewCell.

```
NSDictionary *aTweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.textLabel.text = [aTweet objectForKey:@"from_user"];
```

I am trying to offset the [indexPath row] so it only begins to fill the 2nd Cell as I have a Custom UITableViewCell filling up the first Cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just test for the row number and use the corresponding code, like this:

```
if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
    // take care of the first row
}
else {
    NSDictionary *aTweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]-1];
    cell.textLabel.text = [aTweet objectForKey:@"from_user"];
}
```